# What permissions to read active directory msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData

Tags: active-directory

I need to read the `msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData` property from Active Directory in my C# application.  When I run my code as me, using a normal `DirectorySearcher` I can see many more attributes than when I run as a different user.  My AD administrator told me there should be no difference between the accounts.

Does anyone know the specific permissions that I can have them look at?  The specific item I'm trying to read is where the `pszAttributeName` is `unicodePwd` so that I can get the last change date.

I know about the `PwdLastSet` property but when the account is set to never expire the password that will frequently have the value 0 and so I have to go into the metadata.

This is the code I'm using to run my query.

```cs
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher {
    SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=..."),
    SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
    Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(SamAccountName=...))",
    PageSize = 1000
};

var numFound = 0;

try {
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear();
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData");


    var result = searcher.FindOne();
    foreach (string xml in result.Properties["msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData"]) {
        numFound++;

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("//ftimeLastOriginatingChange[../pszAttributeName='unicodePwd']");
        if (element == null)
            continue;

        Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
    }
} finally {
    searcher.Dispose();
}

Console.WriteLine($"Done - I found {numFound}");
```

On my account it says found 40, and on the other account it says 33.

Comment: Try using `LDAP://` instead of `GC://`. The GC may give you different results, especially if you end up hitting a server on a different domain (if you have more than one domain in your environment).

Comment: OK, once I got the syntax correct the LDAP did solve the issue, thanks!  If you want to make an answer saying to use the LDAP syntax I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LDAP://` instead of `GC://`. The GC may give you different results, because not all attributes get replicated to the Global Catalog. The `msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData` attribute gets constructed at the time you ask for it, so it's up to the server you're asking to construct it. So it's possible that it's only reporting on attributes that were actually replicated to that server.

This would be especially true if you end up hitting a server on a different domain (if you have more than one domain in your environment).